# isinstance(False, int) returns True

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, isinstance

I want to determine if a variable is an integer, so I use the following code:

```py
if isinstance(var, int):
    do_something()
```

but when `var = False`, the `do_something` function is executed.

when `var = None`, the `isinstance()` function works normaly.

Comment: yes. because `bool` objects are `int` objects. IOW `issubclass(bool, int) is True`

Comment: Yes, it seems like the best way for me to check it the variable is exactly an integer is using: type(var) == int

Comment: More idiomatically, `type(var) is int`, since class objects are singletons, in any case, that is more a style issue (although it is slightly faster than using `==`).

Comment: `issubclass(bool, int)` is also `True`. `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `bool` is a subclass of `int`.
You can find it in `builtins.py`

```py
class bool(int):
    """
    bool(x) -> bool

    Returns True when the argument x is true, False otherwise.
    The builtins True and False are the only two instances of the class bool.
    The class bool is a subclass of the class int, and cannot be subclassed.
    """
```

So `issubclass(bool, int)` also `True`.
`isinstance(x, y)` is `True` when `x`'s type is a derived class of `y`'s type.

Answer (score 1):

In `Python3` boolean is defined as a subclass of integer.

That means `True` is equivalent to `1` where as `False` is equivalent to `0`

You can find the more details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html). The exact same explanation from that link is:

`There are three distinct numeric types: integers, floating point numbers, and complex numbers. In addition, Booleans are a subtype of integers`

Answer (score -1):

Python treats `True` as `1` and `False` as `0`. Now what you can do here is:

```
try:
    var = int(string(False))
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid Integer")
```